# How to select all parents which specific children doesnt contain text?

Tags: jquery

I have simple table and i need to select all rows which second cell doesn't contain specific text. I trying to do it like this, but it selects only first occurrence.

```
jQuery('#table').find('tbody tr td:eq(2):not(:contains(disconnect))').parent().hide();
```

Comment: I think you've got `:eq(2)` wrong.  http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ says that it's a zero-based index.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#table").find("tbody tr").each(function(){
   if (!$(this).find("td").eq(2).text().contains("disconnect"))
       $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `.filter()`.

```
jQuery('#table').find('tbody tr').filter(function(){
      return $(this).find('td:eq(2):not(:contains(disconnect))').length != 0;
}).hide();
```